# The format of the date is changed to make a reload in my jqGrid, my date format is changed

Tags: jqgrid

I have the date format in my jqGrid as: `08.13.2015 0:00`

When running a procedural reload from ajax consulting my webService, my database returns the date in this format `2015-08-13T00: 00:00`

I have never seen this format with the T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ISO 8601 format of complete date, plus hours, minutes and seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

The "T" indicates the beginning of the time sequence.